# C# and arrays of anonymous objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays, anonymous-types

What does such an expression mean?

```
obj.DataSource = new[]
{
    new {Text = "Silverlight", Count = 10, Link="/Tags/Silverlight" },
    new {Text = "IIS 7", Count = 11, Link="http://iis.net" },
    new {Text = "IE 8", Count = 12, Link="/Tags/IE8" },
    new {Text = "C#", Count = 13, Link="/Tags/C#" },
    new {Text = "Azure", Count = 13, Link="?Tag=Azure" }
};
```

Especially these lines: new {Text = "IIS 7"... }

How can I create an array like this manually to suit this DataSource.

Comment: By now I think it's safe to change the question title from "C# multidimensional array" to something more appropriate involving "array of anonymous objects" or some such.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

That's not a multidimensional array. That's an array of objects which have been created using [object initializers with anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Answer (score 107):

First, let's reformat [that code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2035017/1) a little:

```
obj.DataSource = new[]
{
    new {  Text = "Silverlight",  Count = 10,  Link = "/Tags/Silverlight"  },
    new {  Text = "IIS 7",        Count = 11,  Link = "http://iis.net"     }, 
    new {  Text = "IE 8",         Count = 12,  Link = "/Tags/IE8"          }, 
    new {  Text = "C#",           Count = 13,  Link = "/Tags/C#"           },
    new {  Text = "Azure",        Count = 13,  Link = "?Tag=Azure"         } 
};
```

This does not look like a multi-dimensional array, but rather like an array of 5 objects. These objects inside the array are of an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), created and initialized using `new { ... }`.

Concerning your question how you can manually create such an array to suit the data source: you seem to be doing exactly that with the above code.

Comment: Correct answer like others. +1 for encouraging proper formatting.

Comment: You, sir, use the formatting of the kings. (Well, except that you need spaces between the ='s signs for the `Lin` word). Nevertheless, I can forgive that as an accident. Proper formatting greatly reduces errors and increases trivially readability.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like an array of anonymous types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: Quote from the article:

You can create an array of anonymously typed elements by combining an implicitly typed local variable and an implicitly typed array, as shown in the following example.


 var anonArray = new[] { new { name = "apple", diam = 4 }, new { name = "grape", diam = 1 }};

Answer (score 3):

Just to add: Anonymous types are converted by the compiler to a real object. So the code will be changed to something equivalent of this (MUCH simplified, only to show that the compiler will create an actual class):

```
internal sealed class AnonymousClass1
{
    internal string Text { get; set; }
    internal int Count { get; set; }
    internal string Link { get; set; }
}
```

And your code will then be changed to:

```
obj.DataSource = new AnonymousClass1[]
{
    new AnonymousClass1 {Text = "Silverlight", Count = 10, Link="/Tags/Silverlight" },
    new AnonymousClass1 {Text = "IIS 7", Count = 11, Link="http://iis.net" },
    new AnonymousClass1 {Text = "IE 8", Count = 12, Link="/Tags/IE8" },
    new AnonymousClass1 {Text = "C#", Count = 13, Link="/Tags/C#" },
    new AnonymousClass1 {Text = "Azure", Count = 13, Link="?Tag=Azure" }
};
```

In one of my programs, I have code like this (simplified!):

```
var myObjects = new []{
    new { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Some Title", Description = string.Empty },
    new { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Another Title", Description = string.Empty },
    new { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Title = "Number 3", Description = "Better than No2, but not much" }
}

foreach(var myObject in myObjects) {
    DoSomeThingWith(myObject.Title);
}
```

This works because it is just another class (I even get IntelliSense) behind the scenes. The benefit is obviously that I just saved myself from creating a class for this object. In my example, all objects need to look the same as well. (Obviously, doing this for any public members would be a bad idea as the compiler might change the name of the anonymous class if you add/remove some)

Answer (score 2):

It's making a new object array, containing a group of anonymous objects.

```
new {Text = "Azure", Count = 13, Link="?Tag=Azure" }
```

is not creating a hash like similar syntax in say php would, but rather real a real object with the properties Test, Count, and Link set.

A good primer for anonymous objects can be found [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/CSharp3-3)

You should be able to use the same syntax to create new structures like this, the property values do not have to be constants:

```
string text = "Azure";
int count = 13;
string link =  "?Tag=Azure";
new {Text = text, Count = count, Link=link }
```

Answer (score 1):

To return such an array from a function I used:

```
public object GetAnonymousArray()
{
    var tbl = new List<object>();
    while (___)
    {
        //fill array in cycle
        tbl.Add(new {Text = someString, Count = someInt, Link = link});
    }  
    return tbl;
}
```