# C# convert postman POST to c# gets bad request (probbaly bad type)

Tags: c#, postman

I was able to complete the following POST via postman:

[image]

I tried to recreate that situation in c#:

```
 var products = new
            {
                name = "test",
                price = 100,
                quantity = 1
            };



            var postModel = new
            {
                merchant_uid = merchant_uid,
                products = products,
                return_url = return_url,
                notify_url = notify_url,
                total_price = total_price,
            };

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, postModel);
```

But isnt that identical, to what I am doing in postman?
I am being returned that: The product Name field is required.

But i am giving it that in my code.
Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: Your screenshot indicates that the parameters are passed as "Query Params" (in the URL) and not via POST. Are you sure that this is not a regular GET with query arguments? Something like `http://myservice/?marching_uid=...&return_url=...&...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending array containing multiple types via Postman and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66885811/sending-array-containing-multiple-types-via-postman-and-c-sharp)

Comment: "you can create a list of products with one item like so: `products  = new List<Product>{products}`" quoting  auburg;

Comment: related for annonimous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035017/c-sharp-and-arrays-of-anonymous-objects

Comment: @Gene no, this definately is a POST

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in creating a type and making a list of that type. Add the objects, and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create array of dictionaries to pass your products, for example:

```
var products = new [] {
  new Dictionary < string, string > {
    {
      "name",
      "test"
    },
    {
      "price",
      "100"
    },
    {
      "quantity",
      "1"
    }
  }
};
```

that is similar what you have in the postman

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but it turned out I needed to create a list :)